# Loading chunk failed in IE 11

Tags: javascript, angular, internet-explorer

My website is built in Angular 5 and it's not working properly in IE 11. I'm getting the error in the console:

[image]

Why my angular code is not working in IE 11? What correction can make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have any hope whatsoever in IE11 you really need to upgrade to Angular 6.

Angular 6 uses webpack 4 under the hood, Angular 5 uses Webpack 2, so you are going to get a whole lot more problems.

Also, take a look at src/polyfills.ts and it will tell you which lines to uncomment for IE support.

Comment: Yes, If I upgrade my angular version it works but my UI style is changing a lot. I know It's weird. Is there any other workaround, I can still use angular 5?

Comment: Not that I know of, we had a similar prob with IE11 and ng6 upgrade was the only fix for us.